# Opening sqlite database connection through Firebase Functions

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-functions

I am wanting to open a Database connection to a pre-existing database on the users' phone when the Firebase function is triggered.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

exports.messageTrigger = functions.firestore.document('newspapers/{articleNr}/articles/{articleNr}').onCreate(
            async (snapshot, _) => {
                if (!snapshot.exists) {
                    console.log('No article found');
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Received');
                newData = snapshot.data();

                let articleNr= snapshot.ref.parent.parent.id;
                console.log('articleNris ' + articleNr);

                let db = openDatabase('TestDB13', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
                db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Article', [], function (tx, results) {
                       console.log(results.rows.item(0));
                    });
                });
}
```

At the moment I am getting the error: "ReferenceError: openDatabase is not defined", in the Firebase Functions Logs.

Is it even possible to access the sqlite database through the index.js file?

Comment: The `openDatabase is not defined` error is because there is no `openDatabase` function defined. Perhaps the function is declared somewhere else, and you need to `require` something to have access to it in this file?

Comment: This question doesn't appear to have anything to do with firebase or google-cloud-functions. If doesn't look like you are trying to connect to sqlite via Firebase Functions either. It seems you are asking how to (in general) connect to an sqlite database. Is that correct or is there more to the question? I want to be sure an answer answers the right question.

Answer (score 0):

you need to import `import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';`